# Disabling lines in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, comments

In PHP I can disable code lines by using `#` or `//` or `/* disabled codes */`.

How do we do it in JS?

Comment: fyi, it's called "commenting out"

Comment: Technically, that doesn't "disable" the line, rather you're editing the line to change it into a comment.  It has the same effect (because the line that was previously code is now just an arbitrary comment), but if you weren't aware that this is why the code no longer executes, it's worth knowing.

Comment: @Nabab; Yes I tried # and it didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `//` or `/* lala */` in JS as well.

Answer (score 5):

`//` will comment all the code afterwards until the next `newline` character, examples:

```
//this whole line is commented. var x=5 has no effect because it's a comment
var x = 5; //x has been set as 5, comment is not whole line.
```

`/*` and `*/` is used to comment everything between them even if it span more than one line. For example:

```
/*
The following code will set x as 5
*/
var x = 5; /* yes it can also span only part of line */
```

Unlike PHP though, `#` is not used to comment code, in this JS is more like C/C++/Java languages.